# Video Processing: replace an image in video frames

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, video, video-processing

I am a ruby on rails developer, so if the answer for this question comes in area of ruby on rails then it will be of super help, but if not then answer in any technical area is also highly appreciated.

**What I am trying to do is, I have a video, in which I want to replace the image(default cursor pointer image) in video frames with the other image that I have.**

I have looked through image processing stuff for detecting the object in frames, but I can not find anything for replacing those objects.

How to replace an object(image) by another object(image) in video frames (in any languages java, ruby, python etc)?

Comment: To answer you questions, #1 - You you can replace an image with another with similar quality. #2. I know a library in Python. Here is the [python_link](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/). I don't know, if this can be achieved in ruby alone. Ok, I'm wrong, it is available for ruby as well, which I never knew. here is the [ruby_link](https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv)

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Thanks for the help, I will check with python and try to implement same in ruby if nothing is there.